# Add a nested table in WordPress to send the data to email as enquiry

Tags: wordpress

I want to create a form to send the enquiry, the visitor wants to add the field given below.

1. Choose anything from 5 given options and give appropriate mark ( a table with two columns, col-a  choose the option (tick), col-b enter marks)

How can I perform this in WordPress.? any plugins to send this information to email as enquiry form